# Visual Studio 2019 CSS (SCSS) multi-line comment issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I recently upgraded to VS 2019 (Windows 10 pro). When commenting out (1) or more lines within a SCSS file, the `*/` is entered on the next line, which makes deletion a pain (please see below examples).

I use `Ctrl + E + C` (as I always have) to comment out (1) or more lines

```
.someClass {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

In the above example, I want to comment out the lines w/ `margin` and `padding`. Therefore, I highlight lines (2) and (3) and use `Ctrl + E + C`.

What is happening is this:

```
.someClass {
/*   margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
*/   font-size: 1rem;
}
```

In the event that I want to delete lines (2) and (3), I know have to delete (separately) the `*/` on line (4).

Expected resolution:

```
.someClass {
/*  margin: 0;
    padding: 0; */
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

**OR** (**preferred**) - (this is how VS 2017 formatted multi-line comments):

```
.someClass {
    // margin: 0;
    // padding: 0;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Is there a keyboard shortcut that is needed to be added/modified, and/or a different shortcut that is already in place for VS2019 that I should use instead?

**Note:**

This does not happen when using `Ctrl + E + C` in `.cshtml` files, `.cs` files, nor `.js` files, only `.scss` files

Comment: I heartily agree with you and would like to see VS2019 replicate the formatted multi-line comments with single-line comments like your preferred sample above. What we have now is a real pain. I searched the editor options for VS2019 SCSS but came up blank.

Comment: I would add that one workaround might be to, as you select multi-lines with your mouse on the left side of lines, before you hit Ctrl + K + C (I'm not sure about your Ctrl + E + C - maybe that's a default of another theme) you can back-arrow once and THEN press Ctrl + K + C and at least the closing multi-line comment will be on the same line as the last line selected. HTH.